# How does Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.1.5.21 stores export password (in XML)?

Tags: xml, oracle, hash, passwords

Does anyone now how Oracle stores the database password for export XML-files?
If you export a file you need to set a "key". In the past the key was stored in this format (example):

In the past:

```
<StringRefAddr addrType="password">         
    <Contents>054D4844D8549C0DB78EE1A98FE4E085B8A484D20A81F7DCF8</Contents>
</StringRefAddr>
```

Now the XML File Contains the password and the "ExportPasswordMode" = Key with a ExportKeyChecksum

for example the db password is "test" and the export key is also test this came out:

```
     <!-- test -->
     <StringRefAddr addrType="password">
        <Contents>8pAMIakpM0k=</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
     <!-- test -->
     <StringRefAddr addrType="ExportKeyChecksum">
        <Contents>r+yjB0bnOhVvLrqH63DruQ==</Contents>
     </StringRefAddr>
```

The ExportKeyChecksum for "test" seems to be always the same, since i exported totaly different connection files on an other computer with the same key "test" with the same result in ExportKeyChecksum

the "password" and "key" looks so base64 encdoed but it isn´t. Does anyone now? Thank you!

[image: ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER EXPORT]

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<References xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/jndi">
   <Reference name="OracleTest" className="oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider" xmlns="">
      <Factory className="oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.DatabaseProviderFactory1212"/>
      <RefAddresses>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="role">
            <Contents/>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="SavePassword">
            <Contents>true</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="OracleConnectionType">
            <Contents>BASIC</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="RaptorConnectionType">
            <Contents>Oracle</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="Connection-Color-For-Editors">
            <Contents>-65536</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="sid">
            <Contents>xe</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="ExportPasswordMode">
            <Contents>Key</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="customUrl">
            <Contents>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="oraDriverType">
            <Contents>thin</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="NoPasswordConnection">
            <Contents>TRUE</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="password">
            <Contents>8pAMIakpM0k=</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="hostname">
            <Contents>localhost</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="driver">
            <Contents>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="port">
            <Contents>1521</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="subtype">
            <Contents>oraJDBC</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="OS_AUTHENTICATION">
            <Contents>false</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="ConnName">
            <Contents>OracleTest</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION">
            <Contents>false</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="user">
            <Contents>mgebbe</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
         <StringRefAddr addrType="ExportKeyChecksum">
            <Contents>r+yjB0bnOhVvLrqH63DruQ==</Contents>
         </StringRefAddr>
      </RefAddresses>
   </Reference>
</References>
```

**EDIT**
SOLVED WITH https://github.com/maaaaz/sqldeveloperpassworddecryptor

```
root@Debian:~/worksapce/sqldeveloperpassworddecryptor# python sqldeveloperpassworddecryptor.py -d test -p 8pAMIakpM0k=
sqldeveloperpassworddecryptor.py version 1.0

[+] encrypted password: 8pAMIakpM0k=
[+] db.system.id value: test
```

Comment: https://github.com/maaaaz/sqldeveloperpassworddecryptor